# How to restrict/allow particular pages using authentication/authorization tags in web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using technology ASP.NET Webforms. I have tried to restrict pages using authentication/authorization tags in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
         <forms name=".ASPXLog" loginUrl="LoginPage.aspx"
             protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" /> 
</authentication>

<authorization>
         <deny users ="?" />
         <allow users = "*" /> 
</authorization>
```

This code restricts all pages except LoginPage. But I would like to restrict specific pages and allow specific pages to visiters. For example x1.aspx, x2.aspx, x3.aspx, x4.aspx pages should be restricted to visiters only those should see who logged in or just registered than pages y1.aspx, y2.aspx, y3.aspx, y4.aspx pages should be allowed to all visiters. How to solve this problem  correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The best and workable approach is to NOT place all that crap in the "main" root web config file (trying to save you from having to spend some days that the building with beautiful green lawns, people walking around in white lab coats, and you spending time in a room with nice padded walls).

So, what this means is that I suggest you create a folder (a sub folder) for any kind of grouping in your site.

Say like this:

[image]

And further down, I have this:

[image]

So, note how I just drop into each folder a web config.

There are HUGE advantages to this. First up, I NEVER have to care or worry about path names for the web page.

In above, we see a contractor’s folder. So, only those logged on the system with a Role of "Contractor" can use that sub folder.

Same goes for SiteAdmin folder. ONLY those logged on with a Role of "SiteAdmin" can use that folder.

So, of course special code (behind) is required to secure such pages.

So, web config for Contractor’s folder looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Contractor" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And for site admin, we have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.web>

  <authorization>
          <allow roles="SiteAdmin" />
      <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />

</system.web>
```

Note how we thus don't have messy path names, and the "security" follows that folder. So, say we move the folder (or even copy it), then we have a ready-made web.config for the security settings of that folder.

So, for most of the logon stuff, the user has to be able to login without elevated rights, so the Accounts folder can't be locked down, else users would not be able to login to the site!!!

So, I STRONG suggest that the root folder be open to everyone, and then upon a logon, you turn on and enable the items in the main menu bar.

While a user may, or may not have the menu items, all pages are thus secured based on their security role anyway.

So, then management of security becomes OH SO much easier, since everything is now by a folder and a simple web.config for each folder. Not some long huge spaghetti mess of a bunch of path names and HARD coded pages in the main root web config.

This setup supports easy development.

I want to add a few new pages for say "Contractors" on the site, then I just simple right click on Contractor’s folder and create/add a new web page. If you hard code and have all kinds of pages in the root web config for security, then EVERY time you start to add some new pages etc., you have to go on some great adventure quest to track down some web configs that WHO KNOWS where they are!!!

Ignore the above, and as I stated, your project will reach a point in which it becomes VERY difficult to manage security settings.

Having stated the above?

Well, ok, a FEW special exceptions can be placed in the main root web.config to setup and secure some web pages, but I would not make a habit of doing this.

Group the security sections (by role) into folders, and thus you can set/change/enjoy a SINGLE and SIMPLE security setting for each such folder. Then you or other developers are now free to simply add new pages to the site, and based on what folder you add new pages, then they will already be secured for you.

And note that the last 10,000 or 20,000 web sites you visited? They ALL allow you to enter the site, land on the main page, and then choose to login or sign up. Or view things like "about" etc.

So, it stands to reason that your root pages should be public, and thus as a result, FEW pages will exist in the root folder. And once again, then adopting a web.config for each sub folder now allows easy management of all pages that you want secured. If you as a developer have to start typing in EACH page to secure in some web.config file, as I stated, you find yourself spending time at that beautiful institution with nice green lawns, and rooms with padded walls.

So, group your pages by a folder, and apply ONE web.config to that sub folder.

And with above, it becomes say rather nice and simple to THEN show/hide menu options in your main menu (probably the master page).

So, when a user hits the site, they say see this:

[image]

Information such as how to login or obtain a logon is displayed.

But, after a user log in?

They see this:

[image]

Now, while my master page DOES turn on the menu items based on role security? It does not matter, since EVEN if a user types in a URL and ignores the menu, all such pages are secured, and I sleep easy at night, since I did NOT miss one single little page security settings in some place.

So, move out the pages you need security for into folders, and then secure by folder. If you start securing page by page, then you not receiving much of any benefits as to having IIS manage your security as opposed to hand coding security, or in your case hand coding the security of each page.

Now, I have quite a few pages that re-direct and jump the user to different location on the site, and this is done with code behind that checks the "role" but the rights to such page(s) is still controlled by each folder having that simple web.config file that controls security for each folder. And thus, once again, we not setting nor controlling security "page by page", but by a folder.

And it turns out having folders for each section of the site means you can find and drill down to ONE section of the site to work on. So, if you working on the super user or site admin pages, they will all be grouped into a folder called SiteAdmin for your development enjoyment. You can even drop in say classes(s) that below to that section of the web site.

So, just like a typical developer breaks out bits and parts of code into sections and separate routines? Do the same for your web layout and that of grouping of web pages. The end result means security groupings of your site also becomes a walk in the park.

Comment: This denies access to a page but when I log in still denies it I made a research but didn`t found a solution.